# how to control the hardware back button in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to go out from the current page and go to the home page. I did this:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
  if ($state.is('kegel') || $state.is('rest')) {
    backAsHome.trigger(function(){
      cancel();
      console.log('Success');
    }, function(){
      console.log('Error');
    });
  }
}, 100);
```

But got this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: backAsHome is not defined
    at Object.fn (controllers.js:108)
    at Channel.hardwareBackButtonClick
```

Comment: what is `backAsHome`? a variable somewhere? a service?

Comment: here is my answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908021/how-can-i-enable-device-backbutton-in-ionic/46912378#46912378